# How can Vue router get current route path of lazy-loaded modules on page load?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue app with router set up like:

```
import index from './components/index.vue';
import http404 from './components/http404.vue';

// module lazy-loading
const panda= () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-panda" */ "./components/panda/panda.vue");
// ...

export const appRoute = [
  {
    path: "",
    name: "root",
    redirect: '/index'
  },
  {
    path: "/index",
    name: "index",
    component: index
  },
  {
    path: "/panda",
    name: "panda",
    component: panda
  },
  //...
  {
    path: "**",
    name: "http404",
    component: http404
  }
];
```

So the panda module is lazy-loaded. However, when I navigate to `panda` page, a `console.log()` of `this.$route.path` in `App.vue`'s `mounted()` lifecycle only outputs

> "/"

instead of

> "/panda"

But index page works well, it shows exactly

> "/index"

as expected.

So how can Vue router get current path correctly of a lazy-loaded page, when page is initially loaded? Did I miss something?

**Edit:**

It can, however, catch the correct path after Webpack hot-reloads. It catches "/" on first visit of `panda`, but after I change something in source code, webpack-dev-server hot-reloads, then it gets "/panda".

So I guess it has something to do with Vue life-cycle.

Comment: This question was asked a long time ago, and with recent versions of vue.js, it has decent support of webpack lazy-loading, and it seems that this is no longer a problem .

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There is a `currentRoute` property that worked for me:

```
this.$router.currentRoute
```

Comment: This worked for me also and this should be the accepted answer. For reference: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute

Comment: I get "TypeError: cyclic object value" using this

Comment: `this.$router.currentRoute.path` ✔

Comment: @SuitBoyApps: yes, it does.

Answer (score 36):

May be you need to use `$route` not `$router`

check here : https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/chyLjpv0/19/

You can also do it by `$router` this way

https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/chyLjpv0/20/

Comment: oops! Sorry I meant $route. That was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: No luck. Neither (<any>this.$router).history.current.path nor this.$route.path gets the correct path when module is lazy-loaded.

Comment: I see in your example, both $route and $router work, and so does my "/index" in this case. But /panda is lazy-loaded, they both still get "/" rather than "/panda".

Answer (score 28):

Use `this.$route.path`. 
Simple and effective.

Comment: This is only available within a component. $router is available in any js

Comment: I used inside html as follows and it works fine. v-if="$router.path === '/dashboard'"

Answer (score 3):

#### Hide Header in some components using the current route path.

> get current route path using `this.$route.path`

```
<navigation v-if="showNavigation"></navigation>
```

```
data() {
    this.$route.path === '/' ? this.showNavigation = false : this.showNavigation = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You have similar problem the correct answer is to use router.onReady and then calling your logic concerning path. Below the official Vue router docs:

router.onReady

Signature:

```
router.onReady(callback, [errorCallback])
```

This method queues a callback to be called when the router has completed the initial navigation, which means it has resolved all async enter hooks and async components that are associated with the initial route.

This is useful in server-side rendering to ensure consistent output on both the server and the client.

The second argument errorCallback is only supported in 2.4+. It will be called when the initial route resolution runs into an error (e.g. failed to resolve an async component).

Source: https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-onready

Comment: router.onReady is not a function

Comment: AS I can see the docs were updated to v4 so You have to look at v3 - https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-onready

Comment: any alternative for those who use v4 like me?

Comment: I think You are looking for this: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#isready

Answer (score 0):

**For vue 3** (Composition API)

It can be as simple as `route.path` if you define the variable route as: `const route = useRoute()`

**Usage example**

If you try the following, each time your route path changes it will console log the current path:

```
<script setup>
 import {useRoute} from 'vue-router'

 const route = useRoute()

 watchEffect(() => console.log(route.path))
</script>
```