# Using v-if for every children route in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I would like to show a certain div for every child route of the route
So I thought simply adding something like this would work, but it does not:

```
<div v-if="$route.path == '/news/:child'">
</div>
```

So any route that is nested under /news/ still does not show that `<div>`

How can I display that div for every child route of the `/news` route?

Comment: $route.path.includes('/news')

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50764862/3462319) and then check if equals `/news`

Comment: @ReeceWard But your solution will display that div for the parent route too if Im not wrong? I want this div only for nested routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually this will work if I set `v-if="$route.path.includes('/news/')"`, thus div only shows in children routes (not in parent).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Vue Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html):

```html
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/news',
    component: NewsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':child',
        component: ChildComponent,
      },
    ]
  }
]
    
// NewsComponent
<template>
  <div>
    My News Component
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

// ChildComponent
<template>
  <div>
    My Child Component
  </div
</template>
```

Will render:

```html
<div>
  My News Component
  <div>
    My Child Component
  </div>
</div>
```